# Error installing and updating client dependencies of project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

Current React Version 17

I am running

```
npm i
```

Result:

```
up to date, audited 2234 packages in 7s

167 packages are looking for funding  run `npm fund` for details

33 vulnerabilities (20 moderate, 11 high, 2 critical)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Then I run

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Result:

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating material-table to 1.63.0,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating react-quill to 0.0.2,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 3.4.4,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN audit Updating node-sass to 4.14.0,which is a SemVer major change.
-react@3.0.3
npm WARN   node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
npm WARN     @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react@"^3.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   29 more (@emotion/react, @material-ui/core, @material-ui/icons, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.4" from material-table@1.63.0
npm WARN node_modules/material-table
npm WARN   material-table@"1.63.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.4" from material-table@1.63.0
npm WARN   node_modules/material-table
npm WARN     material-table@"1.63.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: material-table@1.63.0
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.3
npm WARN   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm WARN     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
npm WARN     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm WARN     4 more (@material-ui/lab, @material-ui/pickers, ...)
npm WARN   14 more (@material-ui/icons, @material-ui/lab, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.8.4" from material-table@1.63.0
npm WARN node_modules/material-table
npm WARN   material-table@"1.63.0" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.8.4" from material-table@1.63.0
npm WARN   node_modules/material-table
npm WARN     material-table@"1.63.0" from the root project
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@3.0.3: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11: please switch to a stable version
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: D:\Coding\Node\node.exe D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\Coding\\Node\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\jjUDIT\\jUDIT.v1.0\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\Coding\\Node\\node.exe" "D:\\jjUDIT\\jUDIT.v1.0\\client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\jjUDIT\jUDIT.v1.0\client\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-30T15_55_11_818Z-debug.log
```

Then I run

```
npm audit
```

to see if something is already fixed... but I got:

```
ansi-html  *
Severity: high
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@0.9.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/ansi-html
  @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin  <=0.5.0-rc.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
  node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts
  webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
  Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
  Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server

ansi-regex  >2.1.1 <5.0.1
Severity: moderate
 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@0.9.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/ansi-regex
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/ansi-regex
  strip-ansi  4.0.0 - 5.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-regex
  node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/strip-ansi
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/strip-ansi
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/string-width/node_modules/strip-ansi
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/wrap-ansi/node_modules/strip-ansi
    cliui  4.0.0 - 5.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    Depends on vulnerable versions of wrap-ansi
    node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/cliui
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/cliui
      yargs  10.1.0 - 15.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of cliui
      Depends on vulnerable versions of string-width
      node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/yargs
      node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/yargs
        sass-graph  2.2.5 || >=3.0.3
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
        node_modules/sass-graph
          node-sass  >=4.14.1
          Depends on vulnerable versions of sass-graph
          node_modules/node-sass
        webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.1.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
        Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
        node_modules/webpack-dev-server
          react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts
    string-width  2.1.0 - 4.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/string-width
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/string-width
      wrap-ansi  3.0.0 - 6.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of string-width
      Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
      node_modules/sass-graph/node_modules/wrap-ansi
      node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/wrap-ansi

browserslist  4.0.0 - 4.16.4
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in browserslist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w8qv-6jwh-64r5
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@0.9.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/browserslist
  react-dev-utils  6.0.0-next.03604a46 - 12.0.0-next.37
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@0.9.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack
        webpack  4.44.0 - 4.46.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack
        node_modules/webpack
          react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts
    webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 4.1.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server

immer  <9.0.6
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in immer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-33f9-j839-rf8h
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@0.9.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/immer
  react-dev-utils  6.0.0-next.03604a46 - 12.0.0-next.37
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts

jspdf  <2.3.1
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-57f3-gghm-9mhc
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install material-table@1.63.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/material-table/node_modules/jspdf
  material-table  >=1.63.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of jspdf
  node_modules/material-table

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: moderate
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@0.9.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts
      postcss-svgo  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 5.0.0-rc.2
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/postcss-svgo
        cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.8
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
        node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
          cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.1.11
          Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
          node_modules/cssnano
            optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin  3.2.1 || 5.0.0 - 5.0.8
            Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
            node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin

quill  <=1.3.7
Severity: moderate
Cross-site Scripting in quill - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4943-9vgg-gr5r
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-quill@0.0.2, which is a breaking change
node_modules/quill
  react-quill  >=0.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of quill
  node_modules/react-quill

33 vulnerabilities (20 moderate, 11 high, 2 critical)
```

So I tried to update all packages...

Running
npm update

Result:

```
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-html-parser
npm ERR!   react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-30T16_01_19_538Z-debug.log
```

I tried also installing with --force or with --legacy-peer-deps and got the same result.

So I want to update my project to the most stable versions of all dependencies and not to have issues later.